# Does MySQL reindex on update

Tags: mysql, index

I have a users table with various fields which are getting updated frequently.
i.e table have:

```
userid -  PRIMARY int
profile_views - int
ratings - int
last_active - int ( to store UNIX timestamps for sorting purpose)
```

I also have an index on `last_active` to get the last active users. When user logins or performs a certain action `last_active` gets updated and same with `profile_views` and `ratings`.

My question is does mysql reindex all table ro reindex index last_active when I update last_active index value or update profile_views or ratings?

table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_address` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `category` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `profile_views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ratings ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `genre_id` (`genre_id`),
  KEY `last_active` (`last_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4059 ;
```

and second table to join to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_genre` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `genre_id` (`genre_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean for "reindex"? On table updates also the indexes are updated.

Comment: for example...if I have 100 rows then I will have 100 inexes in last_active index, If I update one row then does MySQL will update whole last_activite index and or just that row entry in index?  thanks

Comment: It doesn't rebuild the entire index, if this is what you mean. It just updates the entries related to the afftected rows.

Comment: MySQL uses balanced Btrees sometimes it needs to rebuild parts off that tree. But only if an value need to be updated or added in the tree.. this is also the reason why you should not create useless indexes (overindexing) because indexes slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries.

Comment: Can you also post an   show create table statement   here?

Comment: Thread updated with create statement. Thanks

Comment: @Dshah if you insert/update/delete in table users_genre it always need to rebuild some parts of the Btree. In table users it only need to rebuild some parts if you insert or update an id (not wise), userid or genre_id.. but estimating how much needs to rebuild is hard.. to bad MySQL doens't include this CPU cost in EXPLAIN insert/update statements..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not serve you stale data (if that is your question).  The index is maintained and kept up to date as part of every operation (whether be INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.).